# Autocomplete Edittext - Can i read from CSV file?

Tags: java, android, csv, autocomplete, android-edittext

I have a list of ItemCodes that are saved in a CSV file in my raw folder in my android application.

In order to eradicate human error, I would like it so that when the user starts typing the edittext will autocomplete based on the itemcodes in the CSV file.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Here is what I have so far:

```
 private void ReadItemCodes() {
    InputStream IS = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.itemcodes);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(IS, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

    String line;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            //Split by commas
            String[] tokens = line.split(",");

            //Read the data
            ItemCodes+=line;  
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse CSV file into an array in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38415680/how-to-parse-csv-file-into-an-array-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for the Suggestion for the `AutoComplete Edittext` then you can use the `string-array`, it is easier and if you are having some complex Data Structure then CSV is also good.

if you are looking to do it by using CSV then please follow the needful **steps** to read the **CSV** file.

Here you can refer this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/38415815/5343866

Comment: Hi @AbhinavSuman.. ive got as far as reading the CSV file to the list. However, in the adapter for the AutocompleteTextview the last parameter must be a String[]. How do I convert?

Comment: So in which data type you are getting the data from CSV file. If you are getting it in the list then convert it to String[].

Comment: thanks for the help. I was able to find a solution. see below!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes across this in the future. This was the best and simplest approach that I found!

```
 // Get a reference to the AutoCompleteTextView in the layout
    itemcodetextview = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.itemcode);
    batchnumbertextview = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.batchnumber);

    //READ FROM BATCH NUMBER CSV
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.batchnumbers));
    List<String> listbatchnumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        listbatchnumbers.add(scanner.next());
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listbatchnumbers );
    batchnumbertextview.setAdapter(adapter);
    scanner.close();

    //READ FROM ITEM CODES CSV
    Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.itemcodesofficial));
    List<String> listitemcodes = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (scanner2.hasNext()) {
        listitemcodes.add(scanner2.next());
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listitemcodes );
    itemcodetextview.setAdapter(adapter2);
    scanner2.close();
```